# Angular Routing: Is it possible to use different 'path' strings for different languages?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm doing an i18n Angular app, so far it works great.

However I have same route strings for different languages, which isn't best for SEO.

Is it possible to have 'path' properties of Routes array be different for each language?

**Ex:**

```
const appRoutesEN: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Is it possible to define also a `appRoutesFR: Routes` if yes how I can use it?  Shall I inject `LOCALE_ID` to routing module? If so how?

Comment: See https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router and https://github.com/ngx-i18n-router/core , as suggested here https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/178 .

Comment: @estus while they look nice, I'm using Angular's default i18n, not `ngx-translate` and I'd like to see some solution there instead of having yet another dependency.

Comment: Do you build a dedicated app for each language or how do you support multiple locales?

Comment: Hi @PeterFromCologne App was already crated from ground up thinking i18n in mind, from creation of database objects etc, using i18n tools/directives provided by Angular team. `ngx-i18nsupport` package is big help to streamline the process. More on [this here](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/Tutorial-for-using-xliffmerge-with-angular-cli). Only thing those tools can't help is route strings. Route variables are not a problem, if you've been creating your app i18n way, route variables can be translated versions but not route strings.

Comment: @PeterFromCologne as you'll see in that link, you have one code base, but several `npm scripts` to extract strings to be translated and then build/serve in a selected language. Since route strings are only part that can't be in this streamline process, I've created all route definitions in all available languages and before I build in desired language, I comment out that those needed and comment ones not to be used. This is the ugly part and that is because I have lazy loaded modules with child routes. If I didn't I could use @estus' recommended package. If you need more info contact me.

Answer (score 4):

For the moment there seems to be no easy solution for this. I'll update if I find one.

Angular i18n people are working to integrate code level internationalization, maybe then.

Best solution I can come up with is to change routing module(s) in your code and `routerLink` attributes in templates and all links in other parts of your code for each language, then build your app for each language separately.

Not ideal at all.

**UPDATE**

As recommended by @estus, I've tried out [Greentube/localize-router](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router).

I wasn't happy to install dependencies like `@ngx-translate/core` and `@ngx-translate/http-loader` since I'm using Angular i18n implementation/tools and not ngx-translate.

It works till it hits a [lazy-loaded module with child routes](https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router/issues/45).

So if you don't have any lazy loaded module with children, `localize-router` is the way to go.

**UPDATE**

Lazy loaded modules are now supported in the latest version of localize-router.

Angular i18n will be supported once the programatic translations arrive.

Answer (score 4):

If you need different routing per language as you describe in your comment you could have a **dedicated routing module** for each individual language. Then define in the angular-cli.json for **each language a dedicated app** with it's own main.ts and it's own AppModule, pulling in only the routing module required for the particular language.

```
  "apps": [
   {
      "root": "src",
      "name": "yourapp_FR",
...
      "main": "./app/yourapp_FR/main.ts",
...   
    },
   {
      "root": "src",
      "name": "yourapp_DE",
...
      "main": "./app/yourapp_DE/main.ts",
...   
    }
    ]
```

You then build for each language the app like this:

```
ng build --app yourapp_FR --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf --locale fr --i18n-format xlf --aot
```

This way you set it up once and can build each time without commenting out anything.
I do not have the full context. You say having routes per language is better for SEO. I do not understand this, but if you say so, OK. However I would not like dedicated routing for each language. This means a lot of redundancy and more maintenance.

Comment: Wow, seems very doable and logical. Will test it soon. I can bring for example product name (or news title, whatever) as a route variable in selected language, which is better for SEO but in front you see `products` or `news`..etc. Which is not ideal. Not sure "how much" that affects SEO, I'd rather prefer it in selected language.

Comment: Ahh. now I see. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using something like @ngx-translate/core then you can create your own mapping instead of adding more external libraries.

Example:

```
function generateI18nRoutes(
    elements: Array<{ i18nPaths: string[]; component: any; data: object; canActivate?: 
[] }>
): Routes {
    return elements.reduce(
        (accumulator, currentValue) => [
            ...accumulator,
            ...currentValue.i18nPaths.map((path: string) => ({
                path,
                component: currentValue.component,
                data: currentValue.data,
                canActivate: currentValue.canActivate
            }))
        ],
        []
    );
}
```

And then use it like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard],
        children: generateI18nRoutes([{ i18nPaths: [""], component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "ADMIN" } }])
    },
    {
        path: "",
        component: GeneralLayoutComponent,
        children: generateI18nRoutes([
            { i18nPaths: [""], component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "HOME" } },
            {
                i18nPaths: ["sign-in", "iniciar-sesión", "iniciar-sessão"],
                component: SignInComponent,
                data: { title: "SIGN_IN" }
            }
        ])
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        component: PageNotFoundComponent,
        data: { title: "PAGE_NOT_FOUND" }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```